# how do i make this matrix correctly?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, matrix

I'm sorry if this is basic, I need to make this matrix to define the weight for a Gaussian triple quadrature program I'm trying to make.

```
def coefraiz(q):

  x = sym.symbols('x')

  for i in range(1,q+1):
    f =1 

    for j in range(1,q+1):

      if i != j:

        raizj = np.array(sym.solve(Ps(j),x))
        raizi = np.array(sym.solve(Ps(i),x))

        f = f*((x-raizj[j])/(raizi[i]-raizj[j]))

    coef = sym.integrate(f,-1,1)

  M=[coef(raiz)]

  return M
```

Here's the Ps function that the matrix uses, which is functional:

```
def Ps(n):

  x = sym.symbols('x')

  a = 1/(2**n)
  b = 0 

  for k in range(n+1):
    intro = abs(n-k)
    b0 = ((math.factorial(n)) /(math.factorial(k)*math.factorial(intro)))**2
    b1 = (x + 1)**(n-k)
    b2 = (x - 1)**k 
    b += b + b0*b1*b2

  Pn = a*b

  return Pn
```

Comment: I think the actual programming issue that needs solving needs a lot more clarification. I'm not sure about other but I have no idea what a 'gaussian triple quadrature' is. If it is about solving a gaussian triple quadrature itself you may be better in the [maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site, otherwise please elaborate on what the programming implementation issue is :)

Comment: Using sympy and  numpy together is tricky

Comment: So what's wrong? When you run it what kind of error(s) do you get?  Don't just post code and say it doesn't work.  We tend to close that kind of question.

Comment: Some of the problems: `sym.integrate(f,-1,1)` should be `sym.integrate(f,(x,-1,1))`. This gives a number as result, so you can't call `coef(raiz)`. Also, `raiz` is never given a value. Further, `raizi[i]` does not exist because `raizi` only has `i`elements, the last is `raizi[i-1]`. As the order of the numbers in `raizi` is totally arbitrarily, just taking the last element looks strange. The function generates `q` times some value for `coef`, but these `coef` are never saved. You talk about a matrix, but you only generate a 1D list of values. .... ???

Comment: Is `b += b + b0*b1*b2`intentional, are should that be `b = b + b0*b1*b2` ?